# What are the impacts of teachers online activities on their teaching?

Tags: discussion

As an example sometimes we talk about our policies on managing our classes and our reactions to some of our revolted students here in matheducators forum. Sometimes I think what our students do if some of them see our posts here. Maybe it is not a serious problem for those dark lords who live into the shadow of anonymity but what about the others? Should we keep this forum secret like a medieval hidden brotherhood?

On the other hand one could imagine some possible positive aspects of the presence/participation of the students here.

**Question.** What are the possible positive/negative consequences of teachers online activities (particularly here in matheducators.stackexchange) on their teaching?

**Remark.** I am searching for enumerating all possibilities.

Comment: I think this would be better suited to meta, no?

Comment: I would be really happy if I had engaged teachers like all here, struggling to give their best in class.

Comment: @Fantini Of course there are some benefits in it but I am thinking about possible abuses too.

Comment: For it to stay on the main site then I think you should make it a bit more generic.

Comment: @AndrewStacey OK! I think an edit could be useful.

Comment: @user1729 Maybe it is related to meta too because it is about this forum too. But if we look more generalized in the sense of mentioned remark we can see that it is in its right place now.

Comment: @SaintGeorg I wonder if this *should* be a meta question, in the sense that if you want to keep it on main then someone should ask this question on meta anyway. But I am not sure.

Comment: @user1729 Logically this is a paradoxical question because there is a self-reference in it. I add a post in meta about it. However I think it is a very essential question and discussing on its posting place is not really helpful at least here. Please post your comments on related meta post.

Comment: This is definitely a meta question and has been migrated as such. The question does not have anything to do with the pedagogy or teaching of math and instead is about the site itself.

Comment: You don't have to use your real name when posting.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that what I say here can have any bearing on my student's opinion of me. What I state here is public knowledge, as I have said it to them in person in numerous ocasions. If there is something I don't want them to know, I won't say it here.

On a broader issue, you should *always* be careful with what you post on line. What you write today could very well haunt you in a decade's time. (Yes, there are some less fortunate comments of mine on-line that I'd wish I could take back too.)

Comment: You mentioned a really good point on posting online. Thanks.